# Stream or save played sound to a file: File created is too big(50G) using wav.encode

Tags: go, audio, beep

I am using this module for playing sound in my project - https://github.com/faiface/beep
I want to play the sound and stream that played sound to a file or a http endpoint.

```
I am adding streams to mixer like this:
soundMixer.Add(stream)

speaker.Play(s.soundMixer)
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
Any help is appreciated

Exact code where I want this change - https://github.com/ikemen-engine/Ikemen-GO/blob/9fcfb350fc5a1255ab74d264e96b773187e8ad71/src/sound.go#L222-L225

Sample Code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/faiface/beep"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/mp3"
    "github.com/faiface/beep/wav"
)

func main() {

    s1 := getStream("./Lame_Drivers_-_01_-_Frozen_Egg.mp3")
    // s2 := getStream("./Miami_Slice_-_04_-_Step_Into_Me.mp3")

    defer s1.Close()
    // defer s2.Close()

    mixer := &beep.Mixer{}
    mixer.Add(s1)
    // mixer.Add(s2)

    // Instead of initializing the speaker, open a file to save the mixed audio
    outFile, err := os.Create("mixed_audio.wav")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer outFile.Close()

    // Assuming a sample rate of 48000 for the output file, but you should use the sample rate of your input files if they are different
    err = wav.Encode(outFile, mixer, beep.Format{SampleRate: 48000, NumChannels: 2, Precision: 2})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func getStream(file string) beep.StreamSeekCloser {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    streamer, _, err := mp3.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return streamer
}
```

wav.enode does help in saving the sound to a file but the file is too large(50G). It streams the complete sound file at once and probably streams silence to the file. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your programm finished before sounds are played.

```golang
    f, err := os.Open("music.mp3")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    streamer, format, err := mp3.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer streamer.Close()

    speaker.Init(format.SampleRate, format.SampleRate.N(time.Second/10))

    done := make(chan bool)
    speaker.Play(beep.Seq(streamer, beep.Callback(func() {
        done <- true
    })))
    <-done
```

Comment: this code just plays the sound, i want every sound to be be streamed to a file or http which is being played by mixer

Comment: https://github.com/ikemen-engine/Ikemen-GO/blob/9fcfb350fc5a1255ab74d264e96b773187e8ad71/src/sound.go#L222-L225

this place to be exact